# Specify Collection type used in Java

Tags: java, oop, collections

I have a class that contains a collection. I want to be able to specify what implementation is used at runtime. What is the best object oriented way to accomplish this?

```
public class Klazz {
    private class Data {
        ...
    }


    private Collection<Data> collection;

    public Klazz(?) {
    }
}
```

How can I make it so the constructor specifies what type of collection is used to implement Klazz.

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate on why you need different types of collections to internally implement your class.

Comment: Different collections offer different computational complexities for adding elements, removing elements and searching. I want the client to be able to select which implementation they want depending on their needs.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that different collections have different interfaces for storing and retrieiving data.  If you save as a generic collection, then you can only use methods common to collection.

Comment: Then how should I accomplish my goal of allowing the client to pick?

Comment: I suggest editing your question and telling us what this class is supposed to be doing with its data.  By saying your class can use _any_ collection, you are telling us that a consumer could use map, set or list.  Does this even make sense to what you have in mind?

Comment: It stores the data and allows the client to add, remove and search via public methods. I considered the collections of arraylist, linkedlist, treeset and hashset to be viable options.

Comment: So here's the thing, sets don't store duplicates but lists do.  A list can always  he converted to a set, but converting back to a list again won't bring back those duplicate elements.  If this were I, I would write down the requirements and then choose a flexible collection which makes the most sense.  I could argue that the collection you use is none of your client's business.  Maybe the interface you expose is though.

Comment: If the client chooses to use a set it means, they want the collection to remove duplicates, if they have a list they do not.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, List, Set and Queue Interfaces are derived from java.util.Collection Interface. Hence all the objects of any implementations of List, Set and Queue can be referenced by a Collection reference.

For a detailed explanation please refer to this very good guide at [geeksforgeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-in-java-2/)

tl;dr you can do something like:

```
public class Klazz {
  private class Data {
    ...
  }


  private Collection<Data> collection;

  public Klazz(Collection<Data> collection) {
    this.collection = collection;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Klazz k1 = new Klazz(new ArrayList<>());
    Klazz k2 = new Klazz(new HashSet<>());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The classic way to allow a Java client to choose an implementation class is to use a Factory Object supplied by the client to instantiate the object.

Something like this:

```
public interface CollectionFactory {
   <T> Collection<T> create();
}

public class Klazz {
    private Collection<Data> collection;

    public Klazz(CollectionFactory <Data> factory) {
        collection = factory.create();
    }
}
```

(I haven't checked the above with the compiler, so there could be typos, etc)

Passing in a collection object is another solution.  There is potentially an abstraction leakage, but the same is true with a factory object if the factory is "tricky".

It is also possible to pass a `Class` object and use reflection to instantiate the collection.

---

@Tim Biegeleisen has a point though.  The `Collection` API does not constrain the properties of the collection a great deal, and use-cases which will work equally for collections that are lists, sets or "bags" are .... unusual.

Comment: How does this get around the issue that set and list are very different types of collection?

Comment: Perfectly :-).   The client supplies different factories to generate different kinds of collection.  If you want the `Klazz` code to *behave differently* for different collection types, then it can do `instanceof` tests on the collection object that the factory created.

Comment: What's the point of `<C extends Collection<T>>`? That makes the method unsafe and unnecessarily difficult to implement.

Comment: Hmm ... what do you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: To get around the problem of Data being private, you could just make CollectionFactory non generic with a generic method <T> Collection<T> create().

Comment: @StephenC Just return `Collection<T>`. Or replace the whole factory with `Supplier<? extends Collection<Data>>`.

Comment: No problem. +1. That signature also sorts out the point raised by shmosel. It is no longer possible to write e.g. HashSet<?> collection = factory.create();, which makes no sense because it suggests the client of CollectionFactory can choose the class returned.

Comment: Thanks ... I have updated my answer to address all of your points,